# Chef install of readline package fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, recipe

I am trying get PostgreSQL (server) installed on an Ubuntu node using Chef:

**Role definition (roles/base_server.rb):**

```
run_list(
  "recipe[apt]",
  "recipe[postgres::server]"
)

default_attributes(
  postgresql: {
    version:  "9.3.4",
     config: {
      shared_buffers_mb: "12000"
  }
}
```

**Setup**

System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

Chef-Version: 11.14.6

Postgres Cookbook: [3.4.1] (https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql)

**Running the bootstrap command**

> knife bootstrap IPADDRESS -x USER -r 'role[base_server]' --sudo

Results in the following error:

```
* package[readline] action install
  * No version specified, and no candidate version available for readline
  ================================================================================
  Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[readline]'
  ================================================================================

  Chef::Exceptions::Package
  -------------------------
  No version specified, and no candidate version available for readline

  Resource Declaration:
  ---------------------
  # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgres/recipes/build.rb

   29:   package package_name do
   30:     action :install
   31:   end
   32: end

  Compiled Resource:
  ------------------
  # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgres/recipes/build.rb:29:in `block in from_file'

  package("readline") do
    action [:install]
    retries 0
    retry_delay 2
    guard_interpreter :default
    package_name "readline"
    timeout 900
    cookbook_name "postgres"
    recipe_name "build"
  end
```

I already tried to fix this by installing the readline libraries manually, but no success. Has anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You need to include the [apt cookbook](https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/apt) first in your `run_list` to update the apt cache.

Comment: Isn't 'recipe[apt]' in the run list above doing this already?

Comment: I agree. Have you tried running a manual `apt-get update && apt-get install readline`?

Comment: `apt-get install readline` gives me an `E: Unable to locate package readline`. On the other hand doing `apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev` tells me that everything is up-to-date.

Comment: So it's not a chef problem, but more caused by your Ubuntu installation. According [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=readline&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) there is no `readline` package, only a [readline-common](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/readline-common). So this is an issue in the cookbook. But I'm wondering what cookbook you are using. There's no `build` recipe [here](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/tree/v3.4.1/recipes).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by StephenKing, the issue isn't with Chef, it is that the package really doesn't exist. You'll need to fix your recipe code to use the correct package name.